# Как вернуться с Aiogram 3.0.0 на более старую версию?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите как вернуться на более старую версию aiogram?

Я попробовал воспользоваться командой pip install aiogram==2.25.1, но это вызвало очень много ошибок в моём коде, и он перестал запускаться.

Ошибка:

```
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import bot
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .. import types
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import base
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from babel.support import LazyProxy
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\babel\support.py", line 19, in <module>
    from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time, \
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\babel\dates.py", line 29, in <module>
    from babel.util import UTC, LOCALTZ
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\babel\util.py", line 20, in <module>
    from babel import localtime
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    LOCALTZ = get_localzone()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\__init__.py", line 70, in get_localzone
    return _get_localzone()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\_win32.py", line 96, in _get_localzone
    return pytz.timezone(get_localzone_name())
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Misc & Apps\Scripts-Code\Coding v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\_win32.py", line 42, in get_localzone_name
    localtz = winreg.OpenKey(handle, TZLOCALKEYNAME)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Comment: Употребление подобной лексики (по моему) не очень приветствуется)

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей Ваще не приветствуется. Да и качество вопроса тут никаое...

Comment: @SwaD Ну вообще вопрос простой и понятный, да и не оскорбительный ни для кого. Уж лучше так, чем "добавили вебхук и")))

Comment: Парни, спокойно, я всё исправил

Comment: Можете уточнить какая версия была до этого и какие ошибки появляются?

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей Я указал какая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Введите команду `pip install название_пакета`, где `название_пакета` — это название и версия пакета, который вы хотите установить. Вы установили последнюю версию пакета, просто написав название пакета, без указания его версии.
В вашем случае pip install Aiogram== *версия*

Comment: я же говорю я уже пробовал

Comment: Но учитывайте то , что в старых версиях может не быть того или иного функционала. Соответственно вам нужно будет руководствоваться документацией версией того модуля , который используете.

Comment: Я знаю, и у меня уже есть готовый бот, просто после того как я обновился все поменялось и бот теперь не работает и я пытаюьсь вернуться на прошлую

Comment: Необходимо вынести отдельно изменения чтобы посмотреть, что в них конфликтует.
На большее моих знаний не хватает.
Хорошего кодинга!

Answer (score 0):

Удалите pip uninstall aiogram и заново установите pip install aiogram==2.25.1, так же, удалил это, так как, в консоле, написало ошибку, по этим библиотекам babel, jsonschema, click я понял, для старой версии, они не подходят, pip uninstall babel pip uninstall jsonschema pip uninstall click и занаво, их установил и версии ниже стали pip install babel, pip install jsonschema, pip install click.Все работает, прописал эту команду pip freeze и убедился, что стоит, aiogram 2.25.1. Советую, обновить pip install --upgrade update, pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

Comment: "pip install --upgrade update" - эта команда установит какой-то левый пакет [update](https://pypi.org/project/update/), не нужно этого советовать. Ну и проблема же не в невозможности установить предыдущую версию, а в том что после отката ошибки в прогамме вылетают.